# SonarQube - Overall Coverage - C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am wondering why overall coverage is blank?

I have unit test coverage as well as integration test coverage working...

The unit test results include the results for both...

Is there no way to get the overall coverage working?

Comment: what problem are you getting ?? what is your question ?

Comment: Is there anything I need to enable to get overall coverage working? I get unit test coverage and integration test coverage but no overall coverage...

Comment: This feature is currently available for Java only. Feel free to vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARDOTNT-356